# android tethering restrictions

Tags: android, tethering

In android, is it possible to limit the the number of the devices that are connected to the phone via tethering?
The limit by the OS is 10 , is there a way we can reduce this value through an app ??

Or is there a way to restrict the bandwidth of the tethered connections?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No and no, respectively. A custom build of the OS, installed via a modded ROM, presumably can do this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can by using third party Apps like [WiFi Tether for Root Users](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.android.wifi.tether&hl=en). This apps will allow you to select which devices can use your mobile-data connection.